# Disk for fetch is not provided (clickhouse-server.log)

Tags: clickhouse

I am testing replication performance using ReplicatedMergeTree. And I see these messages under in clickhouse-server.log from the being replicated server. It seems that if I configured “Disk for fetch” those message won’t show up. Is there a way that I can configure that?

```
2023.02.24 08:36:08.130007 [ 51336 ] {} <Information> my.table (cb0d20e8-941a-4f45-bdd8-5fc5660348ba) (Fetcher): Disk for fetch is not provided, getting disk from reservation ld2 with type local
2023.02.24 08:36:08.171259 [ 51333 ] {} <Information> my.table (cb0d20e8-941a-4f45-bdd8-5fc5660348ba) (Fetcher): Disk for fetch is not provided, getting disk from reservation ld3 with type local
```

Also from the server where rows are being inserted, I see these. I wonder if I can reduce those logs w/o increasing the log level to Warning.

```
2023.02.24 09:19:12.816280 [ 27971 ] {08b03316-667a-481e-9169-5d457f636371} <Information> executeQuery: Read 4546 rows, 5.51 MiB in 0.05874 sec., 77391.89649302009 rows/sec., 93.77 MiB/sec.
2023.02.24 09:19:12.819625 [ 24292 ] {5b594af4-e675-4abf-908a-ce93e20ebaa9} <Information> executeQuery: Read 4548 rows, 5.51 MiB in 0.054115 sec., 84043.2412454957 rows/sec., 101.80 MiB/sec.
```

With the high insertion rate, lots of logs are being generated.
I am using 23.1.3 with ClickHouse Keeper. Please let me know if more information is needed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform per component overrides of log levels e.g.

```
<!-- Per level overrides:

        For example to suppress logging of the RBAC for default user you can use:
        (But please note that the logger name maybe changed from version to version, even after minor upgrade)
        -->
        <!--
        <levels>
          <logger>
            <name>ContextAccess (default)</name>
            <level>none</level>
          </logger>
          <logger>
            <name>DatabaseOrdinary (test)</name>
            <level>none</level>
          </logger>
        </levels>
        -->
```

Comment: Thanks gingerwizard, it works.
For "Fetcher", I can't make it work; tried "MergeTreeData" as a component.
However, based on the current source, the message is with LOG_TRACE so it's been covered.
https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/master/src/Storages/MergeTree/DataPartsExchange.cpp